# GWT Plugin for eclipse 3.7(helios). i am getting error

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, installation

After selecting google plugin for eclipse and SDK and proceeding next . I am getting error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r37
 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r37)
Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r37
 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r37)
 requires 'org.eclipse.wst.css.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing plugins using the eclipse marketplace? If you're installing plugins by manually entering repositories make sure they have a plugin that's compatible with your version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

As Glenn noted, you need to be very careful with versions here.

It is best to install any ecplise pulgin using an update site.  For Eclipse 3.7, you would use http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 for the GWT update site.

If you were to do a manual install, then make sure to download the correct archive, in your case 3.7, listed here:  https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip

If the installation is giving you trouble, try restarting Eclipse and run it as administrator.  This could be the case if Eclipse is installed in a shared or system directory (e.g. "Program Files").

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected the Android development kit part of the GPE then you need to separately install the Android SDK.  But you don't need that if you are only doing GWT development.  Just uncheck that.